# Is there a version of the "harm principle" geared toward individual's actions?

Tags: ethics, john-stuart-mill

I recently noticed that the Harm Principle was only intended for governance purposes.

"The harm principle is not designed to guide the actions of individuals but to restrict the scope of criminal law and government restrictions of personal liberty."

I assumed that because something caused "no harm", it was assumed it would also be permissible for the individual to do it. But as the harm principle was intended for governance, I was wondering if there is a corresponding principle to guide individual choices where the other party might incur harm based on ones actions?

Comment: Law and morality are not the same thing. They have a lot of overlap, but there are things that are legal but not moral and thin things that are moral but not legal. The Harm Principle is a principle of law, not morality. It is a guide for judges. However, there have certainly been many debates where someone argued that something is not immoral because it does no harm, or that it does no harm except to consenting adults.

Comment: @DavidGudeman " there have certainly been many debates where someone argued that something is not immoral because it does no harm" Thanks! That's exactly what I've been looking for. I've tried finding any school of thought that deals with nuisance/offense that don't qualify as harm and the permissibility of their infliction on others. Unfortunately, to no avail but what you mentioned is definitely the most promising.

Comment: @DavidGudeman I'd also find it difficult to separate law and morality to such a degree, when the harm principle is founded on one's "rights" and so many philosophers (Kant, Aristotle for example) argue that persons who don't utilise their rights are servile.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, the *Harm Principle* is about involvement of a powerful *third party* (or at least *outside* party), and the ethics limiting that party's authority over individual liberty.

Actions *between* individuals, especially between peers, are guided by *general morality*. A popular core principle is the [Golden Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Rule), which has many versions. From Wikipedia:

> The **Golden Rule** is the principle of treating others as one wants to be treated. It is a maxim that is found in most [religions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religion) and [cultures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Culture).[[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:BookSources/978-0-330-48730-6)] It can be considered an **ethic of reciprocity** in some religions, although different religions treat it differently.
> The maxim may appear as a [positive or negative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirmation_and_negation) injunction governing conduct:
>
> - Treat others as you would like others to treat you (positive or directive form)
> - Do not treat others in ways that you would not like to be treated (negative or prohibitive form)[1]
> - What you wish upon others, you wish upon yourself (empathetic or responsive form)[1]

Again, the Harm Principle is a *limit*, or *cap*, on the circumstances of permissible interference. General morality, by which individuals delineate good actions from bad, at least to my awareness, has no such limit. In other words, within the bounds of a person's moral perspective, actions have no inherent ceiling. People may be as good as their hearts desire.