# Is there a corresponding principle to the "Harm Principle" intended for guidance to individuals?

Tags: ethics

I've read on a few sources, including the SEP* that the harm principle is intended for government policy (extended to the structure of a family.)

The point is that I find the harm principle, beyond being vague on the minutia of what constitutes harm, to be a pretty clean principle. So it is a shame is wasnt intended for individuals to model their behaviour by it.

For example, if we assume a situation where person A paid a company for a service, the company messed up and now A needs to be a nuisance to company representative B, who has to go through all the company bureaucracy, although he was about to go home, in order rectify the situation. It is easy to justify why A is entitled to rectify the situation but the harm principle would give a sound argument as to why in his quest for justice A need not shy away from potentially annoying B.

I was wondering if there is an equivalent principle that applies to individual behaviour?

> The harm principle is not designed to guide the actions of individuals
> but to restrict the scope of criminal law and government restrictions
> of personal liberty.
> https://ethics.org.au/ethics-explainer-the-harm-principle/

> *Mill wants the harm principle to have wide scope. He insists that the harm principle regulates more than relations between government and
> individuals. Its application should include the family, in particular,
> relationships between husbands and wives and parents and children (V
> 12)

Comment: Please be more careful with how you handle quotes. You put a quote from The Ethic Center in the same section as a quote from the SEP, and only ever mention SEP as a source. This creates a lot of unnecessary confusion.

Comment: @ETam My bad, fixed it

Comment: See [this related question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/90152/is-there-a-version-of-the-harm-principle-geared-toward-individuals-actions) for a possible answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a version of the "harm principle" geared toward individual's actions?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/90152/is-there-a-version-of-the-harm-principle-geared-toward-individuals-actions)

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice. It's rude to people who are reading questions and trying to be helpful by leaving them unaware of some of the existing comments and answers on the question.